# Consulta MySql con condición

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo un problema al realizar la siguiente consulta:

```
use biotime;
select abstractexception_ptr_id, employee_id, personnel_employee.id, CAST(att_manuallog.punch_time AS 
date) AS 'CurrentDay', DATE_FORMAT(att_manuallog.punch_time, '%H:%i:%s') AS 'Time1',
DATE_FORMAT(att_manuallog.punch_time, '%H:%i:%s') AS 'Time2',
DATE_FORMAT(att_manuallog.punch_time, '%H:%i:%s') AS 'Time3', 
DATE_FORMAT(att_manuallog.punch_time, '%H:%i:%s') AS 'Time4' ,punch_state from att_manuallog inner 
join personnel_employee on personnel_employee.id = att_manuallog.employee_id;
```

En la tabla att_manuallog se guardan los checkint que hace cada empleado y en el campo puch_state se guarda el estado del check, los estados son los siguientes:

- 0 Entrada
- 1 Salida
- 2 Fin de descanso
- 3 Inicio de descanso

Al realizar la consulta que puse al principio me da el siguiente resultado:
[image: resultado]

Lo que quiero lograr es que cada estado del check (puch_state) quede dentro de un Time, por ejemplo si vemos al empleado con el id **147**

[image: consulta]

Alguna manera de por ejemplo fuera algo así en el time se pudiera poner como la condición, sé que no es válida esa manera, pero no sé si haya alguna forma de representar eso. :c

```
DATE_FORMAT(att_manuallog.punch_time, '%H:%i:%s' WHERE puch_state = 0) AS 'Time1',
DATE_FORMAT(att_manuallog.punch_time, '%H:%i:%s' WHERE puch_state = 3) AS 'Time2',
DATE_FORMAT(att_manuallog.punch_time, '%H:%i:%s' WHERE puch_state = 2) AS 'Time3', 
DATE_FORMAT(att_manuallog.punch_time, '%H:%i:%s' WHERE puch_state = 1) AS 'Time4'
```

Comment: Tienes 8 condiciones 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64 si asignas 0, ...,4 a identificar las columnas de tiempo y 8, 16, 32, 64 a los estados puedes registrar en punch_state el identificador asociado a la columna de tiempo sumado con el identificador de estado y siempre guardarás valores inconfundibles y recuperables con un mecanismo simple.

Answer (score 1):

Claro que puedes, como parte de una función de agregación podrías hacer esto:

```
select  abstractexception_ptr_id, 
        employee_id, 
        personnel_employee.id, 
        CAST(att_manuallog.punch_time AS date) AS 'CurrentDay', 

        MAX(CASE WHEN puch_state = 0 THEN DATE_FORMAT(att_manuallog.punch_time, '%H:%i:%s') ELSE NULL END) AS 'Time1',
        MAX(CASE WHEN puch_state = 3 THEN DATE_FORMAT(att_manuallog.punch_time, '%H:%i:%s') ELSE NULL END) AS 'Time2',
        MAX(CASE WHEN puch_state = 2 THEN DATE_FORMAT(att_manuallog.punch_time, '%H:%i:%s') ELSE NULL END) AS 'Time3', 
        MAX(CASE WHEN puch_state = 1 THEN DATE_FORMAT(att_manuallog.punch_time, '%H:%i:%s') ELSE NULL END) AS 'Time4'
        
        from att_manuallog 
        inner join personnel_employee 
            on personnel_employee.id = att_manuallog.employee_id;
        
        group by
            abstractexception_ptr_id, 
            employee_id, 
            personnel_employee.id, 
            CAST(att_manuallog.punch_time AS date) AS 'CurrentDay'
```

- Usamos un `MAX()` condicionado por un `CASE` para tener cada hora
- Si hacemos esto, debemos agrupar por el resto de las columnas.